# XSLT for namespace modify

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT transform which given some xml, I would like it to change the xml's namespace URI.

Input XML:

```
<given xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/6">  
  <child>content here</child> 
</given>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/node()[1]" >
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{concat(substring-before(namespace-uri(), '/6'),'/7')}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<given xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/7">  
  <child xmlns="">content here</child> 
</given>
```

The XSLT transform works as expected but, as you can see, it has included an empty namespace in the child node `<child xmlns="">`. I would like the output child node to just be `<child>`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the root element has `xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/6"` then that namespace applies to all child and descendant elements so basically you need to make sure your XSLT changes the namespace of all elements doing e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{concat(substring-before(namespace-uri(), '/6'),'/7')}" >
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen, that makes sense. Testing using a standard XSLT processor I now get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new default namespace to `xsl:stylesheet`. However, if you really need to do string manipulation to get the new URI, this won't work for you.

**XML Input**

```
<given xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/6">  
    <child>content here</child> 
</given>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/7">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<given xmlns="http://www.sample.co.uk/version/7">
   <child>content here</child>
</given>
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Haley, we actually do need to do the string manipulation as different XML messages will have different URIs (only the version number at the end of the URI is constant). So we can't include the default namespace in the stylesheet itself.